# Create a -resume option in my own bash pipeline

Tags: bash, dependencies, slurm

I am doing a bash pipeline which submit different SLURM jobs having dependencies (as explained [here](https://hpc.nih.gov/docs/job_dependencies.html) or below). If one job crashes, it has to redo all jobs before to succeed for the job that failed once. How can I create a "resume" option where it directly comes back to the job that failed ?

```
job1=$(sbatch ...) # no dependency 
job2=$(sbatch --dependency=afterany:$job1 ...) # dependent on job1 success - PD meanwhile
job3=$(sbatch --dependency=afterany:$job2 ...) # dependent on job2 success - PD meanwhile
```

Otherwise, could a scontrol or something similar be sufficent to come back to the failed job ?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to resubmit a batch script without rerunning all jobs. One way I can think of is saving `jobN_id`'s of `jobN` to a  file say `ids.txt` after each batch submit and then source it back to batch(bash) script. In the batch script utilize  `,afternotok:id`[0] to make sure successfully run job doesn't repeat. But if job B is dependent on job A, not running job B when A is rerun does not make sense. `bash` batch script seems very restrictive, why not use python to submit jobs? [0]https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#OPT_dependency

Comment: Thank you David for your answer, but this is not really what I am looking for. This pipeline is not a big deal and since I am much more familiar with bash, I did not even think of doing it with python. I should give a try

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. You want `-resume` option for your bash script which runs only those `sbatch` jobs which failed on previous runs and ignore those `sbatch` jobs which succeeded?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly this